# Apply style to TreeView children nodes in javaFX

Tags: css, javafx, treeview

I am using JavaFX TreeView and I want to implement a function where if I hover on a tree item, the item and all its children would be highlighted.

So far I managed to use `setCellFactory` to highlight the targeted item like this:

```
treeCell.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        redrawTree()
        treeCell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #0093ff;");
    }
});
```

Result being:

[image]

But I don't know how to target and apply style to treeCell's children. Also this solution requires redrawing the tree a lot which is laggy for big trees.

Can anyone help me go forward or give me an alternative? I think a css solution would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an external css file, do

```
.tree-cell:hover {
  -fx-background-color: #0093ff ;
}
```

Also note that (for moderately complex reasons) if you use `-fx-background` instead of `-fx-background-color`, the text color will react appropriately to the change in background color.

To set styles for child nodes (i.e. nodes that are added to the `TreeCell` as part of its `graphic` property), just do something like

```
.tree-cell:hover .label {
  /* styles... */
}
```

which would style all labels inside "hovered-over" tree cells.

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
public class TreeTest extends Application {  
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {  
        final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();  

        TreeItem<Integer> root = createTreeItem(1);

        final TreeView<Integer> tree = new TreeView<>(root);  
        tree.setCellFactory(treeView -> {  
            final Label label = new Label();
            final Label anotherLabel = new Label("Item:");
            label.getStyleClass().add("highlight-on-hover");
            final HBox hbox = new HBox(5, anotherLabel, label);
            TreeCell<Integer> cell =  new TreeCell<Integer>() {  
                @Override  
                protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {  
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);  
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(hbox);
                    }
                }  
            };  
            cell.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> 
                label.setText(newItem != null ? String.valueOf(newItem) : ""));
            return cell ;
        });  
        stackPane.getChildren().add(tree);  
        final Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);  

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("tree-hover.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.setTitle(getClass().getSimpleName());  
        primaryStage.show();  
    }  

    private TreeItem<Integer> createTreeItem(int value) {
        TreeItem<Integer> item = new TreeItem<>(value);
        if (value < 10000) {
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                item.getChildren().add(createTreeItem(10*value+i));
            }
        }
        return item ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);  
    }  
}
```

with the tree-hover.css file:

```
.tree-cell:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #0093ff ;
}

.tree-cell:hover .highlight-on-hover {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first part works, but not for the children. I don't think in javafx TreeView childrens are part of the parent, from what I understood, a TreeView is just a ListView in which some items are intended to the right to look as children, so .label is not inside .tree-cell:hover, am I wrong?

Comment: Or `.label` might not target anything? I did not find any `label` property in class TreeCell from javafx

Comment: Added clarification and an example

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, and sorry for the late reply. I don't think you understood my problem, your code highlights the label of the hovered item, but I want to highlight the hovered item's children (in my picture they are 2.1 and 2.2)

Comment: The label in my example is a child of the "item". The same technique will work for any node hierarchy you want to put into the cell. I updated it (again) to make it (even) clearer. Please make a bit of effort to understand the code: if it's not doing what you want you really need to clarify your question substantially.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to achieve this is to add and remove a defined a style class on the fly by setting a listener to the row factory.

So the setRowFactory method is responsible to highlight the children nodes.Basically it attaches a listener to an onHover property to each row.

When the changed event is fired we have to check if the row contains a node which is expanded and have children. If so all children will be highlighted on mouse over, and highlighted off on mouse out.

```
private static final String HIGHLIGHT_STYLE = "child-highlight";
private TreeTableView<MyRowContentObject> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();
private void setRowFactory() {
    treeTableView.setRowFactory(e -> {
        TreeTableRow<MyRowContentObject> hoverRow = new TreeTableRow<MyRowContentObject>();
        hoverRow.hoverProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
             //you can use a lambda expression for the listener if you want
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean oldStatus, Boolean newStatus) {
                List<Node> rows = getRowsList();
                //on mouse hover
                if(newStatus){
                    TreeItem<MyRowContentObject> item = hoverRow.getTreeItem();
                    //validates if there is a node on the hovered row, is expanded and has children
                    if(item != null && item.isExpanded() && item.getChildren().size() > 0) {
                        //row index of the last child of the expanded and hovered node
                        int lastChildIndex = treeTableView.getRow(item.getChildren().get(item.getChildren().size() - 1));
                        //highlights the childs
                        for (int i = hoverRow.getIndex() + 1; i < lastChildIndex + 1; i++)
                            rows.get(i).getStyleClass().add(HIGHLIGHT_STYLE);
                    }
                } else {
                    //on mouse out cleans every single row, because its hard to keep track of the highlighted rows
                    for (Node row : rows)
                        row.getStyleClass().remove(HIGHLIGHT_STYLE);
                }
            }
        });
        return hoverRow;
    });
}

//fetches all rows from the treeTableView
private List<Node> getRowsList(){
    return new ArrayList<>(treeTableView.lookupAll("TreeTableRow"));
}
```

And add this to you styles.css or whatever other name you defined:

```
.child-highlight {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 11, 44, 0.28);
}
```