# JavaFX TreeView -- change background CSS on sibling nodes on MouseEvent

Tags: javafx, treeview, scalafx

I am trying to implement onMouseEnter and onMouseExit events on a JavaFX ListView.  What I want to do is if the mouse moves over a node of the list view, I want to change the background color of the nodes that are currently visible children in the current view.

This post has a great code sample, but is not quite what I am looking for.
[Apply style to TreeView children nodes in javaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307349/apply-style-to-treeview-children-nodes-in-javafx)

Using that code as a reference, what I am looking for is a given tree:

Root -> Item: 1 -> Item: 100 -> Item 1000, Item 1001, Item 1002, Item 1003

When I mouse over  "Item: 100" I would like it and Item 1000* to have a background color change.

This seems difficult to me because the getNextSibling and getPreviousSibling interface is on the TreeItem and though you can get a TreeItem from a TreeCell on the MouseEvent, you can't (that I know of) update CSS on a TreeItem and have it take effect in a TreeCell -- because the setStyle method is on the TreeCell.

Suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Update note: I originally had a solution using a subclass of `TreeItem`. The solution presented here is much cleaner than the original.]

Create an `ObservableSet<TreeItem<?>>` containing the `TreeItem`s that should be highlighted. Then in the cell factory, observe that set, and the cell's `treeItemProperty()`, and set the style class (I used a `PseudoClass` in the example below) so the cell is highlighted if the tree item belonging to the cell is in the set.

Finally, register `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` handlers with the cell. When the mouse enters the cell, you can get the tree item, use it to navigate to any other tree items you need, and add the appropriate items to the set you defined. In the `mouseExited` handler, clear the set (or perform other logic as needed).

```
import java.util.HashSet;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HighlightingTree extends Application {

    private final PseudoClass highlighted = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("highlighted");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeView<Integer> tree = new TreeView<>();
        tree.setRoot(buildTreeRoot());

        ObservableSet<TreeItem<Integer>> highlightedItems = FXCollections.observableSet(new HashSet<>());


        tree.setCellFactory(tv -> {

            // the cell:
            TreeCell<Integer> cell = new TreeCell<Integer>() {

                // indicates whether the cell should be highlighted:

                private BooleanBinding highlightCell = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
                    getTreeItem() != null && highlightedItems.contains(getTreeItem()), 
                    treeItemProperty(), highlightedItems);

                // listener for the binding above
                // note this has to be scoped to persist alongside the cell, as the binding
                // will use weak listeners, and we need to avoid the listener getting gc'd:
                private ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (obs, wasHighlighted, isHighlighted) -> 
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(highlighted, isHighlighted);

                // anonymous constructor: register listener with binding    
                {
                    highlightCell.addListener(listener);
                }
            };

            // display correct text:
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (newItem == null) {
                    cell.setText(null);
                } else {
                    cell.setText(newItem.toString());
                }
            });

            // mouse listeners:
            cell.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
                if (cell.getTreeItem() != null) {
                    highlightedItems.add(cell.getTreeItem());
                    highlightedItems.addAll(cell.getTreeItem().getChildren());
                }
            });

            cell.setOnMouseExited(e -> highlightedItems.clear());

            return cell ;
        });

        BorderPane uiRoot = new BorderPane(tree);
        Scene scene = new Scene(uiRoot, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("highlight-tree-children.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TreeItem<Integer> buildTreeRoot() {
        return buildTreeItem(1);
    }

    private TreeItem<Integer> buildTreeItem(int n) {
        TreeItem<Integer> item = new TreeItem<>(n);
        if (n < 10_000) {
            for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
                item.getChildren().add(buildTreeItem(n * 10 + i));
            }
        }
        return item ;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

highlight-tree-children.css:

```
.tree-cell:highlighted {
    -fx-background: yellow ;
}
```

Comment: James_D : First off thank you for the obvious thought and consideration you put into this question.  Let me mentally review  your response and get back to you.

Comment: I fairly strongly recommend just jumping to the second (updated) version. I left the original in there for completeness, but perhaps I should delete it.

Comment: James, I did just that. I have just tried it out and it really what I was after.  Very nice!  Thanks.

Comment: Hi James, I think the comment about weak listeners does not apply here. To the best of my knowledge, the listener will be added as is, not wrapped in a `WeakChangeListener`. Weak listeners are used when combining bindings by the fluent API (e.g. `highlightCell.not()`) or via factory methods from `Bindings`, but not when adding listeners explicitly. Indeed, if I inline the listener above into the `addListener(...)` call and call `System.gc()` right after that, everything still works fine.

Comment: If I make the binding and listener local variables, garbage collection breaks the binding - I think it's the listener created to implement the binding in `Bindings.createBooleanBinding(...)` that is the issue (so probably the comment is in the wrong place).